# What is a good approach for creating an adventure game for android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to start making an point-and-click adventure game for android. The problem is that I don't quite know where to start. I already have some minor Java experience. I know how to the basic stuff, handling threads and showing images on a canvas, but that's about it.

Do you suggest I develop the game from scratch or should I use a game engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developing with Native framework is fine, especially if it is not a project with a deadline and you want to do it only as a hobby or for self-learning purposes. It could teach you a lot since you are going to struggle with every fine detail of the game by yourself. But if it is a project with a strict deadline, I suggest that you look for one of the game engines around.